# Call Android activity from React-Native code

Tags: android, react-native

I am using REACT-NATIVE to build android app.
I want to call android activity from React-Native code. (say when I clicked the button in my react native code, it should call android activity)

I have 4 class files

- MainActivity.java (created by react-native when opened in android studio)
- MainApplication.java (created by react-native)
- Login.java (android activity file)
- Example.java (android activity file)

Want to achieve following flow:

Login.java -> React-Native js -> Example.java

I already went through following links, but unable to understand

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32825290/4849554

Similar question asked here

[React Native Android: Showing an Activity from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41698230/react-native-android-showing-an-activity-from-java?wb48617274=E8FBB78B)

Answer (score 51):

To start an Android activity, you need to create a custom native module. Assume one called `ActivityStarter`; it might be used from JavaScript as follows:

```
import { ..., NativeModules, ... } from 'react-native';

export default class DemoComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <View>
            <Button
                onPress={() => NativeModules.ActivityStarter.navigateToExample()}
                title='Start example activity'
            />
        </View>
        );
    }
}
```

`ActivityStarter` is just a Java class that implements a React Native Java interface called `NativeModule`. The heavy lifting of this interface is already done by `BaseJavaModule`, so one normally extends either that one or `ReactContextBaseJavaModule`:

```
class ActivityStarterModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    ActivityStarterModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "ActivityStarter";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    void navigateToExample() {
        ReactApplicationContext context = getReactApplicationContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExampleActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

The name of this class doesn't matter; the `ActivityStarter` module name exposed to JavaScript comes from the `getName()` method.

The default app generated by `react-native init` contains a `MainApplication` class that initializes React Native. Among other things it extends `ReactNativeHost` to override its `getPackages` method:

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            new MainReactPackage()
    );
}
```

If you're adding React Native to an existing app, [this page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html) has you override your `Activity`'s `onCreate` as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(getApplication())
            .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
            .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")
            .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .build();
    mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "HelloWorld", null);

    setContentView(mReactRootView);
}
```

Note `addPackage(new MainReactPackage())`. Regardless of which approach you use, you need to add a custom package that exposes our custom module. It might look like this:

```
class ActivityStarterReactPackage implements ReactPackage {
    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
        modules.add(new ActivityStarterModule(reactContext));
        return modules;
    }

    // UPDATE: This method was deprecated in 0.47
    // @Override
    // public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
    //     return Collections.emptyList();
    // }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Finally, update `MainApplication` to include our new package:

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            new ActivityStarterReactPackage(), // This is it!
            new MainReactPackage()
    );
}
```

Or you can do `addPackage(new ActivityStartecReactPackage())` to `ReactInstanceManager.builder()`.

You can find a [complete, self-contained example here](https://github.com/petterh/react-native-android-activity).

---

**UPDATE**

`createJSModules` was removed from the `ReactPackage` interface in version 0.47, and has been commented out of the sample. You'll still need it if you're stuck with an older version of RN for some reason.

---

**UPDATE MARCH 2019**

[The sample project](https://github.com/petterh/react-native-android-activity) now supports similar functionality for iOS.

Comment: Hi @peter can you please tell whether this is possible to do? One Android app is integrated with RN..where page A is in Android and page B is in RN..on click of a button in page A, RN activity started and page B get loaded..so my Q is can the button on page A can be RN component instead of native Android

Comment: @Peter, Would it be possible to contact you privately?

Comment: If it's via button's interface then I am able to use it. My requirement is a bit different. I want to launch activity directly without any interactions. Is it possible

Comment: I don't think that should be a problem. `NativeModules.ActivityStarter.navigateToExample()` doesn't have to be called as the result of clicking a button.

Comment: Hi، im tring to the similar thing. I want to launch my app with some paramter to route in headlesstask forground service.  I tried your code in my module with main action. got the error. Cant find activity for intent. Can you help me pleae.