# How do I Expose a React Method on an Android Activity with a ReactRootView so it can be Called From React Native Javascript?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have an existing application on both the iOS and Android platforms. Before I start migrating code completely over to React Native, I am dipping my toe in the water by simply displaying a react view in response to a button press from a native view in the app(s).

Now, I am trying to wire up a native function which I can call from react-native javascript code.

I have already done this successfully using iOS. But I'm not sure how to extend the code from the docs in the page I linked previously to make it work in Android.

I didn't find the React Native docs to be clear enough on how to make this happen on Android.

I have an android app with an activity which I created according to the instructions found in the react-native docs at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps .

How do I expose the function? and how do I invoke it from Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out how to do this with the help of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42253397/call-android-activity-from-react-native-code) and [this page](http://www.techup.co.in/call-native-android-activity-from-react-native/).

My mistake was I was trying to put the method I wanted to expose in the java code for the android activity. That was not the correct approach.

Instead, here's what I had to do:

1. After following [the instructions to integrate react-native into an existing Android app](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps), create a native module (a class that extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule).

   For the sake of this example, lets call the module `JNativeCalls`
2. Create a native module package (a class that implements ReactPackage). Let's call it `JNativeCallsPackage`
3. In the java activity, add the `JNativeCallsPackage` ReactPackage to the code that sets up the ReactInstanceManager using:

   ```js
   .addPackage(new JNativeCallsPackage())
   ```

   This line should be placed on a line right after the line that says `.addPackage(new MainReactPackage())` if you have followed [the same instructions I did](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps#the-magic-reactrootview)
4. Then, import the package into the javascript file:

   ```js
   import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';
   ```
5. Finally, from within your javascript, call the method with:

   ```js
   NativeModules.YourCustomModuleName.helloWorld("A string message parameter");
   ```