# Does react-native-navigation creates an activity for every screen in android platform?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I have seen that [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) provides a completely native navigation for react-native. And I know that react-native applications run on a single activity (MainActivity.java) on Android. So my question is: does react-native-navigation creates an activity for every screen? If no what are functionalities that make this library native and running on a single activity?

**Edit**
I think that my question wasn't clear, I'm not asking if we can call an activity from react-native. I'm asking if this library [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation), which provides a native navigation, creates other activities ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call Android activity from React-Native code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42253397/call-android-activity-from-react-native-code)